# How should a "role" choice list be presented in a professional "choose your own adventure" scenario?

Tags: users, homepage, dynamic-ui

I have to get a homepage visitor to specify their level of professional seniority in a "choose your own adventure" style of commercial pitch (so that the pitch is relevant to their job function). Once the choice is made, the page scrolls to the relevant content. There are three choices (people who do the work, people who manage a functional division, and top level management).

Here's a group of buttons with fontawesome icons:

[image: buttons]

Well, it's better than a drop-down select list in this instance, but it still doesn't strike me as very good. Or attractive.

Is there a better way to present these choices?

Comment: Are they logged in?

Comment: No, this is the public homepage where the CTA is to create an account.

Comment: As long as the titles mean something to your users and, once the account is created, you don't force them to choose each time, I think this looks clear enough.

Comment: The buttons seem fine, but maybe you need to focus on the lead in and out? Centered, larger, and the only content on the page (with maybe a header) makes them clear CTAs. Selecting one could mark it as active and display additional info about the choice made. Then offer the ability to select a different role before hitting some sort of "next" button? Again, the buttons themselves are fine, but context can play a big role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about when user clicks one of them, showing a dialog with dark opacity background, the dialog is telling the description, information for the role, Why dialog is better than scrolling? The dialog makes user more focused with their choice, and should finish the steps you made.

Anyway, for the color maybe you can try different color for each button to make more obvious for users to see those are different role.